# How to read the notations in the proof of the inclusion-exclusion principle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, inclusion-exclusion

This question is a follow up to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500192/please-help-to-complete-proof-of-inclusion-and-exclusion-principle) question.

How do I create a sequence from this formula?

> $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i) - \sum\limits_{1\le i < j \le n-1}P(A_i \cap A_j) + \dots + (-1)^n P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_{n-1})  - \left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}P(A_i \cap A_n) - \sum\limits_{1\leq i < j \leq n-1}^{n-1}P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_n) + \dots + (-1)^nP(A_i \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_{n-1}\cap A_n)\right]$

My confusion is in interpreting $(-1)^n P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_{n-1})$ and $(-1)^nP(A_i \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_{n-1}\cap A_n)$.

Take $(-1)^n P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_{n-1}$ as an example. I don't know where $n$ should begin. I thought it is $1$ but if $n=1$ then the first term, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i)$, should have a negative sign because $(-1)^1=-1$. Since this is not the case, it must mean that $n$ starts from 2. But this not mentioned anywhere in the theorem.

Lastly, based on Antoine's answer, how do I formally complete the proof? I can see that the missing terms in the first line can be found in the second line and that the final term in the second line will always be the last term as per the theorem. But I don't know the sequence of steps to write so that the end of this proof is a formula as per the theorem.

Comment: Note for $n=1$ you have $P(\emptyset) = 0$ so all is fine.

Comment: @AlexR I thought if $n=1$, then I should end up with $P(A_1)$. If that is not the case, how do I get $P(A_1)$ from this formula?

Comment: Notice how this is $$P(A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_{n-1})$$ And $A_0$ isn't really defined at all; you get $P(A_1)$ with $n=2$

Comment: @AlexR Thanks. I understand it now. But I still don't know how to formally complete the proof. Would you be able to help?

Comment: Well, just take the $(-1)$ in front of the brackets and multiply it. notice $i\leq n-1 \Rightarrow i<n$ to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P(A_i) - \sum\limits_{1\le i < j \le n-1}P(A_i \cap A_j) + \dots + (-1)^n P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_{n-1})  - \left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}P(A_i \cap A_n) - \sum\limits_{1\leq i < j \leq n-1}^{n-1}P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_n) + \dots + (-1)^nP(A_i \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_{n-1}\cap A_n)\right] = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{|\alpha| = k} (-1)^{k + 1} P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^{|\alpha|}A_{\alpha_i}\right)$$
Where $\alpha \in ([1,n]\cap\mathbb N)^{k}$ is a multiindex with $i < j \Leftrightarrow \alpha_i < \alpha_j$ and $|\alpha|=k$ is its length.
Just try to formalize it a bit. You'll notice that for example
$$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n-1} P(A_i\cap A_j) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} P(A_i \cap A_n) = \sum_{1\leq i<j \leq n} P(A_i \cap A_j) = \sum_{|\alpha| = 2} P(A_{\alpha_1} \cap A_{\alpha_2})$$

---

See [here](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section6-2.pdf), page 215 for a brief explanation ("principle of inculsion and exclusion")

Comment: The notation $\alpha \in [1,n]_{\mathbb N}^{k}$ is new to me. Is there some online site I can read up to better understand it (along with examples)?

Comment: $[a,b]_{\mathbb N}$ is a short version of $$[a,b] \cap \mathbb N$$
The exponent $k$ is just the $k$-dimensional carthesian product of the set. $\alpha$ is a vector of length $k$ containing strictly increasing natural numbers between $1$ and $n$.

@mauna I also added a reference in the post ([this](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section6-2.pdf)). Does it help?

Comment: yes, I finally got it! Thanks so much for your help.